# For which type of potentials a Schrödinger operator will have discrete spectrum?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory

Let $-\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} x^2} + V(x)$ be an one-dimensional Schrödinger operator for a given potential $V(x)$. Is it possible to know if such operator has a discrete spectrum (or not) without solving the eigenvalue problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could start here: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/08/08-191.pdf

Comment: A sufficient condition is for the Schrodinger operator to be compactly resolved.

Comment: The grandmaster on this topic is probably Barry Simon. Rather than me passing on references it would probably be easier for you to look him up yourself, e.g., on mathscinet.

Comment: There is a characterization of when the spectrum is purely discrete (quick version: exactly when $V\to\infty$ in a suitable sense). See my answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278568/harmonic-oscillator-discrete-spectrum/278598#278598

Comment: On the other hand, if you are asking if it's possible to detect if the operator has *some* discrete spectrum, then there's a lot on that too but no very general complete answer (there can't be one because existence of eigenvalues may depend on small details).