# Spectrum of a Hamiltonian on the real line

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics, schrodinger-operators

Consider the following linear (Hamiltonian) operator on functions on the real line $\mathbb{R}$
$$H\psi(x)=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x)+V(x)\psi(x).$$

Assume that $V$ is a smooth function and $V(x)\to +\infty$ as $|x|\to +\infty$.

> Is it true that the spectrum of $H$ is discrete?
>   In my case $V$ is a polynomial of fourth degree. If the answer is negative in general, is it positive in my case?

Comment: Sure it is (the resolvent of your operator is compact). Also, you can argue along the lines of that questions https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278568/harmonic-oscillator-discrete-spectrum

Comment: @Sascha: Thanks. It seems that an answer there contains the answer to my question too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Harmonic oscillator discrete spectrum](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278568/harmonic-oscillator-discrete-spectrum)